# ios 7 - choose photo from gallery covers status bar

Tags: image, ios7, statusbar, picker

In an ios 6 app, if I use `UIImagePickerController` and select to choose photo from gallery, the gallery appears without covering the status bar.

However, in ios 7, the gallery covers the status bar.

Any idea how to prevent covering the status bar in ios 7?